# "О себе вообразил" или "из себя вообразил"?

Tags: выбор-слов

Похоже, обе эти фразы являются правильными. Есть ли между ними смысловая разница?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Оба варианты верны** и связаны (1) с воображением героя другой личностью или (2) с представлением себя в особой ситуации, где он может проявить эти новые личностные качества. Таким образом, смысловая разница **в разной  тематике.**

**Из словаря:**

**ВООБРАЗИТЬ** св. 1. кого-что и с придат. дополнит. Мысленно представить себе, вызвать в сознании какой-л. образ. Живо вообразил себе эту встречу. Вообрази, как там красиво.   2. кого (кем, чем) и с придат. дополнит. Ошибочно предположить, счесть. В. себя поэтом. Вообразил бог знает что!

**Примеры**

1. Вообразил себя кем-то, изобразил из себя кого-то:

*Потерял бдительность, расслабился, забыл про осторожность, понадеялся на свой опыт, **вообразил из себя** суперагента.*

2. Вообразить себя в какой-то ситуации.

*― Приз дали, так уж и **вообразил о себе,** что дамы перед ним расстилаться должны, ― послышался из толпы злобно-шипящий голос.*

Answer (score 0):

Разница проявляется в таких предложениях:

```
Из себя вообразил почет и уважение. // некорректно
О себе вообразил почет и уважение.
```